# How to test a ServiceStackController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, servicestack, moq

I use a `SupplierController` class and its `SupplierControllerTest` class to verify my expectations.

If my `SupplierController` class inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller then the test runs OK.
If my `SupplierController` class inherits from `ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController` then the test throws an exception.
I am using **Moq** to test it.

Here are both classes:

**Test class**

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class SupplierControllerTests
  {
     [Test]
     public void Should_call_create_view_on_view_action()
     {
        var nafCodeServiceMock = new Mock<INafCodeService>();
        var countryServiceMock = new Mock<ICountryService>();
        var controller = new SupplierController();
        controller.NafCodeService = nafCodeServiceMock.Object;
        controller.CountryService = countryServiceMock.Object;

        nafCodeServiceMock.Setup(p => p.GetAll()).Returns(new List<NafCode> { new NafCode { Code = "8853Z", Description = "naf code test" } });
        countryServiceMock.Setup(p => p.GetAll()).Returns(new List<Country> { new Country { Name="France"  } });

        var result = controller.Create() as ViewResult;
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    }
 }
```

**Controller class**

```
  public class SupplierController : ServiceStackController
  {
     public ISupplierService SupplierService { get; set; }
     public IManagerService ManagerService { get; set; }
     public INafCodeService NafCodeService { get; set; }
     public ICountryService CountryService { get; set; }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
       var model = new SupplierModel();
       model.Country = "France";
       return View(model);
     }
   }
```

**SupplierModel class**

```
  public class SupplierModel
  {
     public string Country { get; set; }
  }
```

The error thrown is:

> Test 'SupplierControllerTests.Should_call_create_view_on_view_action' failed: System.MethodAccessException : Échec de la tentative d'accès de la méthode 'SupplierController.Create()' à la méthode 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(System.Object)'.
>       Controllers\SupplierController.cs(51,0): à SupplierController.Create()
>       Controllers\SupplierControllerTests.cs(33,0): à SupplierControllerTests.Should_call_create_view_on_view_action()

Translated this means:

> Access to the method 'SupplierController.Create()' failed.

Comment: Any internal class anywhere? is ToEditModel class internal?

Comment: Added the SupplierModel class after your good remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a crack at it. I don't know what version of MVC you're using but my guess is that ServiceStack is compiled against an older version. You will need binding redirect. Now usually, the binding redirect is added as part of the MVC project templates but in your unit test project, you'll have to do manually (this explains why you only experience this error in your unit test).

In your unit test project app.config (this example is to redirect from MVC2 to MVC3. Adapt it to your case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```